How to confirm PNP transistor is valid?
I am practicing with some basic circuits based on bipolar and MOSFET transistors and have faced with an interesting behavior. I have to extract my PNP transistor from a circuit and have found it traces a signal between its pins as it should not be.
Bipolar transistors should give a drop in voltage between base and two others pins (~0.7V, but might vary). In case of PNP transistor (A684) a positive probe on a base (pin 3) and a negative probe on a collector (pin 2) or an emitter (pin 1) shows zero voltage (0V) on multimeter display which is set it diode tracing mode. It is a PNP transistor, so negative\ground probe should stay on base pin.
However, when I put a positive probe on a base (pin 3) and a negative probe on an emitter (pin 1), it shows drop in voltage (~0.7V). Also a positive probe on collector (pin 2) gives a drop in voltage between collector and emitter (pin 1) which should not happen at all if there is no voltage on base!
I double checked my theoretical knowledge about bipolar transistors work by this publication (note: it has not correct data in pictures, but data in tables are ok!), so it should work like this.
I have a set of 10 transistors which I recently bought in the shop. I knew the case when a whole delivery from a Chinese manufactory was broken, but because I am new in electronics I might miss an important thing here which I hope to spot and understand with your help. Thanks!

@ Gleichmut - you have checked your "theoretical knowledge about bipolar transistors" by using the linked publication, which does not say anything about how a BJT really works?

@LvW It is a wrong link, I just updaded with a correct one. Do you have anything to say regarding the question? Do you agree on what I should expect from PNP transistor and the data I measured tell us it is broken?

Show us the circuit diagram of a circuit that you have built.

@G36, the question is not related to a circuit. I used a circuit from a Horowitz and Hill book (2.11), but it is for NPN transistors and I can not use PNP transistors instead which I have in stock.

So the RED probe to Base? And the black probe to the emitter or collector gives you a 0.7V reading on DVM set on the diode tester? Thus, means that you have an NPN transistor.

@G36, no, when the RED probe to Base and the black probe to the emitter I have voltage drop only between base and emitter, there is no voltage drop between a base and a collector

Are you sure that this leg is BASE, not a emitte?  Because it looks like that. This is why you have no voltage drop between the "base" (emitter) and the collector.

@G36, I used datasheet for references (see link in the post). Indeed for such transistors pin 2 is usually a BASE, but  datasheet claims pin 3. However, even datasheet lies and this is a NPN transistor with BASE on pin 2, it should show voltage drop between base and emitter AND between base and collector. Let's stop speculation on this and return back to an origin question to avoid misleading others who might want to join a discussion

Take a look here https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1016224/MCC/2SA684.html

@G36, that's great! This implementation has opposite base and emitter. When we consider pin 1 as a BASE everything works as an expected!. How does it possible to have transistor under the same code, but from different manufacturer to have differences in design? Is it common?

0V should never appeared in diode test of bjt.

@G36, you could post your reply as an answer, I will accept it to close the topic.

In both datasheets it is a same marking, just one linked in your question is a bit misleading because it’s bottom viewed.

Test the transistors in a different circuit to see if the issue persists. Check the datasheet and implement an application circuit for testing.

From your measurement result it looks like you have misinterpreted the transistor pinout. Your base is an emitter in reality.
Here you have a clear view of a pinout:

The Panasonic datasheets show the same pinout but are viewed from the bottom.

And this is why you were confused.

I thought Panasonic image shows transistor projection from the top view, electrodes here just a projection from the bottom view. Thank you for made it clear.
